# Is it ok to have an empty subclass that extends an abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass

Consider the following:

```
  public abstract class Item {
     String name;
     String description;
     //concrete getters and setters follow
  }

   public class InventoryItem extends Item {
     //empty subclass of Item 
   }

  public class CartItem extends Item {
     int quantity;
     int tax;
     //getters and setters for quantity and tax follow
  }
```

InventoryItem represents an item that is available for sale whereas CartItem represents an item that is added to the cart so it has additional properties such as quantity and tax. Is it alright to have an empty subclass of the abstract class Item in this scenario?

Option 2 : We could have an empty Item interface. InventoryItem will implement Item and define name and description properties and have getters and setters. CartItem will extend from InventoryItem and will define quantity and tax as properties and have getters and setters.

Option 3 : Would it be better to have an Item interface. InventoryItem would implement Item. We could then have a CartItem class that 'has-an' Item and two properties namely tax and quantity

Comment: Nothing functionally wrong with it, from a design stand point it seems a little finicky.

Comment: That is exactly what I am worried about. IS this wrong from a design point of view? See my edit! Can you explain why it is wrong from a design point of view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is nothing wrong with this design: it clearly designates `Item` as a base, and `InventoryItem` / `CartItem` as instantiable classes. I would rename `Item` to `AbstractItem` (Java class libraries do this) to underscore the fact that the intended use for the class is to be used as a base for other classes.

There are C++ - specific issues, such as [assignment through the base pointer](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/020163371x/items/item33.html), that make it very desirable to make all "non-leaf" classes abstract. Although the rule does not translate to Java literally, I think it is still a good idea to make non-leaf classes abstract, even when the class is self-sufficient. This helps you make explicit separation between classes intended for direct instantiation and classes intended for extending, which is good for maintenance by people who are not familiar with your code base.

Taking the rule a step further, it is a common practice in Java to make all leaf classes `final`. This is a good defensive rule, especially when your classes are immutable.

**EDIT :** As far as modeling items in the cart goes, inheriting is not the best option. In fact, I think it is a wrong thing to do. I would make my `CartItem` own an `Item`, rather than extending it, because the item does not become another kind of entity by being placed in a cart. Here is how I think it should be modeled:

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    String description;
    ...
}

public class CartItem {
   Item item;
   int quantity;
   int tax;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Does java have any empty implementations of an abstract base class? Also, would it be better to go with option2 from my post to be on the safer side or are you absolutely sure I can sell this to an architect?

Comment: @bot The only two changes I'd make to your design would be renaming `Item` to `AbstractItem`, and adding a protected constructor to the class. The `InventoryItem` would no longer be empty, because it would need to present a public constructor. I think an empty interface is actually worse, because it does not convey any meaning to the reader. Replacing `Item` with an interface is only marginally better, because you miss an opportunity to reuse the logic that checks and/or produces the common attributes.

Comment: That makes sense. What would be better in AbstractItem, a no-arg protected constructor or a constructor that initializes all the parameters. I think a no-arg constructor makes more sense since that will not make the getter and setters redundant.

Comment: @bot The answer depends on whether or not you intend the `AbstractItem` as mutable or immutable. If your design needs it to be mutable, a parameterless constructor is better; if it needs to be immutable, a constructor with all parameters is preferred.

Comment: I am developing this application as an assignment for an interview. Taking that into consideration, I think a parameter-less constructor would suffice for now! Is it really not alright to have an empty class? Is the constructor necessary?

Comment: @bot It is absolutely OK to have an empty class, but it is a good idea to make constructors of abstract classes protected, too. Java's classes often do it, e.g. `AbstractPreferences`, `AbstractCollection`, `AbstractDocument`, and so on. I follow this rule in my code, both in Java and in C#, so in the end I have no truly empty classes (although one may argue that a class that does nothing besides publishing a constructor is still an empty class).

Comment: Alright. Ill think about the constructor part once more. I have one more question. I only need to use the CartItem class in my application. I added the InventoryItem class just to make the reviewer understand that InventoryItem is an item in the inventory where as CartItem is an item in the cart. Will the above implentation be as effective even if I don't demonstrate the InventoryItem class?

Comment: +1 I agree except for make all leaf classes final.  This is rarely done, even within the Java libraries and very annoying to future developers.

Comment: @bot I do not think there are much performance implications of extending an abstract class. Since you do not plan to use inventory item in your design, however, I think there is a better way to model what you're building. Take a look at the update.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your example. CartItem should not extend Item right?

Comment: @bot Yes, this is correct - it should not extend `Item` (fixed).

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Is there a need to have an interface that is implemented by Item or is that not necessary since Item is practically a JavaBean

Comment: @bot I would not bother with an interface for the `Item` either.

Comment: Yea that's what I feel. But I have seen so many solutions out there that use an ItemIntf and Item implements it. See this for example : http://programming-artifacts.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/workspaces/hacking/invoice/src/com/google/code/progrartifacts/sales/invoice/model/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14820/discussion-between-bot-and-dasblinkenlight)

Comment: @bot There's a difference between production systems and interview questions, though: I'd avoid adding unnecessary classes to my design, because of the risk to confuse your reviewer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer a slightly longer suggestion, or an opinion, which might provide some guidance.

When designing is-a hierarchy I tend to make distinctions only in behaviors through polymorphism.
In general, I tend to avoid distinction between objects by data only. 
Over the years, I even stopped created inheritance hierarchies for struct-like "data objects" on the sole basis of what variables they hold.

Where I spend most time is in defining the common interface for the abstraction class represents in terms of methods and then having subclasses that are all amenable to the same interface, but with different behaviors. (Liskov Substitution Principle)

In this case, I would consider a common interface/abstract Item class with hierarchy of Item implementations that differ in how they stock, calculate their taxes, etc. I could have a method .isInCatalog() that would tell me where is item or what is its nature if I have to handle it differently, but I would still try to encapsulate most of the item-type specific logic into the implementations of its polymorphic methods.

Although these types of calculations are usually in practice done in a batch/aggregate operations on a database and not in a single object, I would have on abstract level .getTax(), .getQuantity() and then have sub-classes with different behaviors. 
( Consider NullObject refactoring for do nothings to avoid handling nulls)

Few principles that aid this design are outlined here in this solid blog post:

http://codebork.com/2009/02/18/solid-principles-ood.html